# iOS policy on third party website rendering inside app

Tags: android, iphone, react-native, google-play, app-store

I have a react native app and I need to open third party websites inside my application. Will it be inappropriate to open inside a web component(in app browser) of the app? Or, shall I open it in a default safari browser?

Will iOS bar my app if I open third-party websites inside my app's web view? And what about google?

Comment: Depends on the content of those sites. Do they allow purchases, can them be 18+ etc.? Highly depends on the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases displaying external web content directly in your app is fine. I have had to do this my self on a number of occasions.

However Max is right it depends on the content. Explicit websites would almost certainly cause your app to be rejected. There does seem to be an exception for user generated content which is described at point 1.2 User Generated Content of the App Store Review Guidelines

Things like a shop to purchase physical products or services is fine, but if you was offering to sell a subscription to access content in your app or to buy gold coins to use in your game app this would be seen as trying to circumnavigate Apples in-app purchase system.

You should check out the App Store Review Guidelines https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/